# Making a sha1-hash of a row in Oracle

Tags: oracle, hash, sha1

I'm having a problem with making a sha1-hash of a row in a select on an Oracle database. I've done it in MSSQL as follows:

```
SELECT *,HASHBYTES('SHA1',CAST(ID as varchar(10)+
  TextEntry1+TextEntry2+CAST(Timestamp as varchar(10)) as Hash
FROM dbo.ExampleTable
WHERE ID = [foo]
```

However, I can't seem to find a similar function to use when working with Oracle.
As far as my googling has brought me, I'm guessing dbms_crypto.hash_sh1 has something to do with it, but I haven't been able to wrap my brain around it yet...

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The package [DBMS_CRYPTO](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_crypto.htm) is the correct package to generate hashes. It is not granted to PUBLIC by default, you will have to grant it specifically (`GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO TO user1`).

The result of this function is of datatype `RAW`. You can store it in a `RAW` column or convert it to `VARCHAR2` using the `RAWTOHEX` or `UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE` functions.

The `HASH` function is overloaded to accept three datatypes as input: `RAW`, `CLOB` and `BLOB`. Due to the [rules of implicit conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/datatypes.htm#sthref422), if you use a `VARCHAR2` as input, Oracle will try to convert it to `RAW` and will most likely fail since this conversion only works with hexadecimal strings.

If you use `VARCHAR2` then, you need to convert the input to a binary datatype or a `CLOB`, for instance :

```
DECLARE
   x RAW(20);
BEGIN
   SELECT sys.dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(col1||col2||to_char(col3)), 
                               sys.dbms_crypto.hash_sh1) 
     INTO x 
     FROM t;
END;
```

you will find additional information in the documentation of [`DBMS_CRYPTO.hash`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS664)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had to use the value dbms_crypto.hash_sh1 stands for (the integer 3) instead of the constant to make it work when doing a regular SQL.

    SELECT sys.dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(col1),3) FROM t;

Comment: I don't think this is exactly correct for 11g R2. `dbms_crypto.hash` seems to have 3 overloaded versions for `raw`, `blob` and `clob`. `varchar2` value has to be explicitly converted to `raw` either with `utl_i18n.string_to_raw` or `utl_raw.cast_to_raw`. Or use `clobs` for character data.

Comment: What if there are some columns which don't have string data type?

Comment: The comment above from @PrometheusDrake talks about `dbms_crypto.hash_sh1`. To be clear, this is a constant defined in the package and passed to `dbms_crypto.hash` as the typ parameter. It indicates that the SHA-1 hash algorithm should be used.

Comment: @ca9163d9 If your column is another type, look for the appropriate UTL_RAW package function. For example, if you had a column of type NUMBER, use CAST_FROM_NUMBER to convert it to RAW, then encrypt. To reverse, decrypt, then CAST_TO_NUMBER.

Answer (score 9):

The DBMS_crypto package does not support varchar2. It works with raw type so if you need a varchar2 you have to convert it. Here is a sample function showing how to do this :

```
declare
  p_string varchar2(2000) := 'Hello world !';
  lv_hash_value_md5    raw (100);
  lv_hash_value_sh1    raw (100);
  lv_varchar_key_md5   varchar2 (32);
  lv_varchar_key_sh1   varchar2 (40);
begin
  lv_hash_value_md5 :=
     dbms_crypto.hash (src   => utl_raw.cast_to_raw (p_string),
                       typ   => dbms_crypto.hash_md5);

  -- convert into varchar2
  select   lower (to_char (rawtohex (lv_hash_value_md5)))
    into   lv_varchar_key_md5
    from   dual;

  lv_hash_value_sh1 :=
     dbms_crypto.hash (src   => utl_raw.cast_to_raw (p_string),
                       typ   => dbms_crypto.hash_sh1);

  -- convert into varchar2
  select   lower (to_char (rawtohex (lv_hash_value_sh1)))
    into   lv_varchar_key_sh1
    from   dual;

  --
  dbms_output.put_line('String to encrypt : '||p_string);
  dbms_output.put_line('MD5 encryption : '||lv_varchar_key_md5);
  dbms_output.put_line('SHA1 encryption : '||lv_varchar_key_sh1);
end;
```

Comment: The example above uses `cast_to_raw`, however callers should use `UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW` instead. `cast_to_raw` doesn't take into account a binary independent language conversion. If the default language of the database is changed between encrypt and decrypt, the `cast_to_raw` and subsequent `cast_to_varchar2` may fail. For example, the varchar2 could be converted with: `UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW (string, 'AL32UTF8')`

Answer (score 5):

Just to put it here, if someone will search for.

In Oracle 12 you can use `standard_hash(<your_value>, <algorythm>)` function.
With no parameter `<algorythm>` defined, it will generate SHA-1 hash (output datatype `raw(20)`)

Answer (score 3):

You can define this function in your favorite package, I defined in utils_pkg.

```
FUNCTION SHA1(STRING_TO_ENCRIPT VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
BEGIN 
RETURN LOWER(TO_CHAR(RAWTOHEX(SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(STRING_TO_ENCRIPT), SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH_SH1))));
END SHA1;
```

Now to call it

```
SELECT UTILS_PKG.SHA1('My Text') AS SHA1 FROM DUAL;
```

The response is

```
SHA1
--------------------------------------------
5411d08baddc1ad09fa3329f9920814c33ea10c0
```

You can select a column from some table:

```
SELECT UTILS_PKG.SHA1(myTextColumn) FROM myTable;
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 19c:

```
select LOWER(standard_hash('1234')) from dual;
```

which is equivalent to

```
select LOWER(standard_hash('1234','SHA1')) from dual;
```

will return an SHA1 hash.

For alternative algorithms see: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/STANDARD_HASH.html

Comment: best thanks! this is my want