# Is there an MD5 Sum function in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, md5, md5sum

In Oracle SQL, is there an MD5 function or something available to me?  I would like to do something like...

```
select name, md5_sum( name ) from person;
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1749753/272735 The answer is basically the same even the hash algorithms are different (MD5 vs. SHA1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [this Tahiti Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_obtool.htm#ARPLS67278). Under **MD5 Procedures and Functions** it says *These subprograms generate MD5 hashes of data. The MD5 algorithm ensures data integrity by generating a 128-bit cryptographic message digest value from given data.*

Also note, that `DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT` is deprecated and can/should be replaced with `DBMS_CRYPTO`, see [this Tahiti Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm#i1002022)

Comment: Thanks for the link...now I need to pitch this to some DBA to get it available to me.  Oh well...at least it exists, just not OOB functionality.  Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You may want to check the [DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_obtool.htm#ARPLS67278) procedure.

Here is an example:

```
     SQL> column md5_val FORMAT A40
     SQL> SELECT DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.md5 (input => UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw('Eddie')) md5_val
       2    FROM DUAL;
     MD5_VAL
     ----------------------------------------
     E5F6C83E6E97C74FC9E9760FC8972AED

     1 row selected.
```

Comment: `DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT` is deprecated at least since 11g R2. Use `DBMS_CRYPTO` instead. (Or `STANDARD_HASH` in 12c.)

Answer (score 12):

In 12c you can use [STANDARD_HASH](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/functions178.htm#BABCCAFF).  It's available by default, does not require any PL/SQL objects or hard-coded values, and is not deprecated.

```
SQL> select standard_hash('Finally, an easy way to do this.', 'MD5') md5
  2  from dual;

MD5
--------------------------------
456E4D024B4BB704169E21DEB895B0E2
```

Answer (score -4):

don't think it comes with it right out of box. you need to define your own.