# How to get same hash for numbers in Oracle and in C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, encryption, hash, oracle12c

In my Oracle 12c database I have sequential primary keys I want to encrypt using SHA256 (SHA1 might suffice too) so that when using them in URLs it will not be easy to guess other relevant keys.

As I understand I can use Oracle 12c's `STANDARD_HASH` function to compute these. For example:

```
select standard_hash(5000000884, 'SHA256') from dual;
>> 340B6B758A184AD6A17959278F1419AF180CCAA26CC53D39853E45F572523E0D
```

I can create an index on the table using that function. I will also need to generate the same hash in C# so that later I can match it to the index. I tried using `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed` to compute the same hash but its `ComputeHash` method only accepts either a `string` or a `byte[]` while I have a `decimal`.

I can get the same hash results if I treat the numbers as strings both in C# and in Oracle, but that's probably unnecessary overhead I want to avoid.

I guess the main gap is that I don't know how Oracle treats a number as input to a hash function since I can't even get the same result for:

```
new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(new byte[]{0})
```

and:

```
select standard_hash(0, 'SHA256') from dual;
```

How can I get same hash for numbers in Oracle and in C#?

**EDIT:**

Though it doesn't effect the question it may be relevant for alternative solutions, but I also want my URLs to be short so I will later convert them to base 62. Also, I don't want to provide my primary keys in the URL to prevent the ability to use them through other interfaces.

Comment: How to hash numbers is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749753/making-a-sha1-hash-of-a-row-in-oracle), but I have no idea how to mimick that in C#

Comment: You say "encrypt" and then you say "using SHA256". This is not encryption. Hashing is done on bytes so the question here is how Oracle is translating a number into a sequence of bytes.

Comment: Is it an option to just convert the id's to a string first before hashing?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen You're right. I guess "encode using SHA256" would have been a better choice of words.

Regarding converting to a string, it is possible. I'd just rather avoid it if I can manage getting the same hash values in C# because I'd be able to save work both in Oracle and on my server running C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same hash value for a number in PL/SQL and in C#, you'll need to convert the number to a binary format first, which is identical in both languages.

The proper package in PL/SQL is `DBMS_CRYPTO`, which accepts `RAW` as datatype. Presumably, your sequential primary key has the datatype `NUMBER`, which has an Oracle defined internal structure.

You could choose for instance a hexadecimally formatted string as the common format:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id NUMBER);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (10);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (100);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1000);

SELECT id, HEXTORAW(to_char(id, 'fmXXXXXXXXXXX')) as hex,
       DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(hextoraw(to_char(id, 'fmXXXXXXXXXXX')), 3) as sh1  
  FROM t ORDER BY id;

ID   HEX   SH1
1    01    BF8B4530D8D246DD74AC53A13471BBA17941DFF7
10   0A    ADC83B19E793491B1C6EA0FD8B46CD9F32E592FC
100  64    3C363836CF4E16666669A25DA280A1865C2D2874
1000 03E8  ABA6A1729AEA932DFB085F66C3D1E9882E275F7E
```

(this is SH1 as I am on 11.2 right now)

I would add this hash as a virtual column to the table (to have the hashing code at a central place). If you want to select by the hash, I'd add an index on this virtual column:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD (secret RAW(2000) GENERATED ALWAYS AS(
  DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(hextoraw(to_char(id, 'fmXXXXXXXXXXX')), 3)));

CREATE INDEX ti_hash ON t(secret);

SELECT * FROM t;

ID    SECRET
1     BF8B4530D8D246DD74AC53A13471BBA17941DFF7
10    ADC83B19E793491B1C6EA0FD8B46CD9F32E592FC
100   3C363836CF4E16666669A25DA280A1865C2D2874
1000  ABA6A1729AEA932DFB085F66C3D1E9882E275F7E

SELECT * 
  FROM t  
 WHERE secret=hextoraw('ABA6A1729AEA932DFB085F66C3D1E9882E275F7E');
```

To get this code working, your schema user (the owner of the table) needs the privilege directly (not via a role):

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_CRYPTO TO my_schema_owner;
```

Comment: (1) Are you saying Oracle is using some internal structure, that isn't easily reproducible outside Oracle, to represent numeric primary keys (or numbers in general) and that whatever bytes that are stored in that structure are the bytes that are being hashed?

And if that is the case, as you mentioned in your answer, converting the number to a string is not really overhead because I can't easily reproduce the numeric representation in my C# code anyway. (2) Why use a virtual column and index on that instead of a function-based index on my original column?

Comment: 1) Yes, the internal format to store numbers is undocumented and rather complicated, see [here](http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/number_format.html) for instance. Yes, converting a number to a string is not really overhead in my view.

Comment: 2) Reusability: To use a function based index FBI, you need to hit the very syntax before the index is used, for a virtual column you use normal SQL. Besides, technically, the function based index is doing exactly the same. It creates a (hidden) column and puts an index on it. In my recollection, the FBI got implemented first by Oracle, and they exposed the syntax via virtual columns in a later release. But it's your decision, of course...

Answer (score 0):

You can compute a MD5 hash:

```
var hash = MD5.Create();
var computed = 
hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello"));
var finalvalue = (decimal) (BitConverter.ToInt32(hashed, 0));
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the hash of a number (e.g., 5000000884) - not a string (e.g., "Hello")?

Also, I prefer using one of the SHA algorithms, since the chance for collision is lower. It might not be much of a difference for my needs but I'm a worrywart.

Comment: @shwartz the ComputeHash method takes a byte array as parameter. In that previous code, it converts the string to a byte array as well. Use the `BitConverter.GetBytes` method to convert an integer to a byte array. For decimals, decimals have the 'GetBits' method that returns an int array, which you can then turn into byte arrays.

Comment: Alternatively decimals can be converted to strings and then be hashed, which may or may not work depending on your use case.

Comment: @Burak I tried using BitConverter and also getting the hash of the byte array of a string (using ASCII) but that doesn't get me the same result as the one I get from Oracle.

Comment: @shwartz Try `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` to get the byte array from the string. Also ensure the string representation of the decimal is the same as the input in Oracle

Comment: @Burak If I understand correctly (and I have verified that, using UTF8 for the above as well) digits in UTF8 are represented the same as in ASCII. So, the results were the same for both encodings. Also, in Oracle i have a number and not a string representation of a number. I tried hashing a string representation of the number in C# and in Oracle and the results were different from the result of hashing a number in Oracle.

Comment: Aaaah ok, you can compute the hash in a both sites. I work every day with Oracle and this System is very explicit for Java, if the hash is computed in Oracle and, logically core of Java, is possible but Oracle runs internally with PKCS. Depending of arquitecture you can see JWT, GUID or a Random Generate Number with save in Oracle and referencing it with params in url ... I use WEB-API and is very secure and faster with index ...

Answer (score 0):

Besides your solution to encrypt the primary key, you could alternatively add a random column which cannot be guessed.

```
CREATE TABLE example (id number PRIMARY KEY, secret BINARY_INTEGER, ...)

INSERT INTO example (id, secret, ...) 
VALUES (myseq.nextval(), dbms_crypto.randominteger, ...)
```

The URL is only genuine if it's secret matches that of the database:

```
?id=12&secret=14746383&...
```

So you would separate the database stuff (identity of a row, anchor for foreign keys, access by index) from the security stuff (accept only genuine URLs).

Comment: That would work and get around the hash generation issue, but I'd still need to add an index for that column as I do now so I'd rather just add a function-based index on my primary key.

Comment: No, you don't need an index on the "secret" column. That's why we came up with the solution. You identify the row with the normal primary key (which you need anyway), and then doublecheck that the query is genuine. Of course this is done with a single SELECT statement.

Comment: Oh, I now understand what you meant. That would work but I'd rather keep a short URL, without providing my primary keys or adding another column. I'm sorry I didn't mention this before. I edited my question.

Comment: It's just an idea :-). I would stick the hash function in a virtual column, too.